# post data for foreign key in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

```
public class SectionProperties {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long section_id;
    @Column( columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private Long section_no;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="assessment_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private AssesmentProperties foreign_key;
    private String section_type;
    private int weightage;
    private int time;
    private int No_of_questions;
    //getters and setters
}
```

this is my model class.There is foreign key from another table AssessmentProperties .now when iam posting the data with postman my data looks like this

```
"section_type":"hard",
"weightage":2,
"time":2,
"no_of_questions":3,
"foreign_key":{
    "assessment_id":1
}
```

but my input should be looking like this

```
"section_type":"hard",
"weightage":2,
"time":2,
"no_of_questions":3,
 "assessment_id":1
```

can anyone say me what should i do for this?
and by the way this is the controller for post method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SectionProperty",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Long> createOrUpdateoptions(@RequestBody SectionProperties model)
{
    SectionProperties updated=properties.createOrUpdateSections(model);
    return new ResponseEntity<Long>(updated.getSection_id(),new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: How do you generate that post data? It looks correct in terms of JSON conversion. Because you have an object called foreign_key of which type is AssesmentProperties and probably only the join column (assessment_id) is enough for Hibernate.

Comment: in postman i post the data like in the first input and works fine i wanted to post the second input

Comment: Well then don't use an entity class as a model class. Create your own model which includes the properties as you want. It's not a good idea to use your entity classes as domain models.

Comment: ok fine got your idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SectionProperties as `@RequestBody` param, make a custom *DTO* *(DataTransferObject)* class that will look like this in JSON format:

```
"section_type":"hard",
"weightage":2,
"time":2,
"no_of_questions":3,
"assessment_id":1
```

And like this in POJO:

```
public class SectionPropertiesDTO {
    private int assessment_id;
    private String section_type;
    private int weightage;
    private int time;
    private int no_of_questions;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then your method should look like this, note that you will have to change your logic to convert from DTO object into entity and vice versea:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SectionProperty",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Long> createOrUpdateoptions(@RequestBody SectionPropertiesDTO model)
{
    // TODO: change the createOrUpdateSections to convert from DTO into entity;
    SectionProperties updated=properties.createOrUpdateSections(model);
    return new ResponseEntity<Long>(updated.getSection_id(),new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```